# Replace space character between two numbers

Tags: python, string, replace

I need to replace space with comma between two numbers

```
15.30 396.90 => 15.30,396.90
```

In PHP this is used:

```
'/(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)/', ','
```

How to do it in Python?

Comment: In `php` I would use [`strtr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php). :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways to do it (sorry, [Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)). Which one to use depends on your input:

```
>>> s = "15.30 396.90"
>>> ",".join(s.split())
'15.30,396.90'
>>> s.replace(" ", ",")
'15.30,396.90'
```

or, using `re`, for example, this way:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("(\d+)\s+(\d+)", r"\1,\2", s)
'15.30,396.90'
```

Comment: The first approach will replace all whitespace with commas, not just between numbers.

Comment: @F.J I understand, the OP hasn't provided any additional info on what the input looks like. Thanks.

Comment: (Trivia: Python has some [optimizations for different `replace` operations](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c?view=markup#l2347) making it faster than the `split/join` operation.)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the same regex with the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) in Python:

```
import re
s = '15.30 396.90'
s = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)', ',', s)
```