# Python regex finditer's second group got ignored by first captured group

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have the following string.

```
input = "a b c d e f 1 2 3 4"
```

I have the following regex code.

`input = re.sub(r"([0-9])\s+([0-9])", "\1\2", input)`

This basically is trying to remove the spaces between just digits.

However, after running that code, I got the following result.

```
input = "a b c d e f 12 34"
```

The space between 2 and 3 wasn't replaced.

Is there a way to solve it without running the sub twice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22767354/3832970

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't a dupe of that one ... None of the accepted answers there are helpful here ... Basically, OP is already _doing_ what was suggested there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since two space separated digits are matched it will not get again in next match. What you can do is use [positive look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for second digit. Aldo you can use `\d` short handle for digit group `[0-9]`.

```
input = re.sub(r"(\d)\s+(?=\d)", "\1", input)
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/gG0qK9/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]